# RecyclerView - CardViews overlap each other when scrolling (How to add multiple rows to a single CardView?)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

The entire layout is set like this - A RecyclerView that contains several card views, and each cardview can have multiple rows of LinearLayouts of exact type (but with different data).

Everything works okay, except when I scroll down or up, the Cards begins to overlap over other cards randomly.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{

    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            LinearLayout ll_parent = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_linearlayout, null, false);
            NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);
            String URL = "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.png";
            networkImageView.setImageUrl(URL, VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
            networkImageView.setLayoutParams(contentParams);
            networkImageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            TextView tv_card_title = new TextView(context);
            tv_card_title.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            LinearLayout ll_title = new LinearLayout(context);

            ll_title.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            ll_title.addView(networkImageView);
            ll_title.addView(tv_card_title);
            ll_title.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            ll_parent.addView(ll_title);

            for (int j = 0; j < getItemCount(); j++)
            {
                LinearLayout ll_children = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_views, null, false);

                Button bt_delete = (Button) ll_children.findViewById(R.id.bt_delete);
                bt_delete.setTag("card no: " + (position+1) + " Iteration: "  + (j+1));
                bt_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
                Button bt_edit = (Button) ll_children.findViewById(R.id.bt_edit);
                bt_edit.setTag("card no: " + (position + 1) + " Iteration: " + (j + 1));
                bt_edit.setOnClickListener(this);

                TextView tv_abc = (TextView)ll_children.findViewById(R.id.tv_abc);
                tv_abc.setText("ABC");
                tv_abc.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                tv_card_title.setText("ABC");
                tv_card_title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                NetworkImageView iv_Image = (NetworkImageView)ll_children.findViewById(R.id.iv_Image);

                iv_profileImage.setImageUrl(URL, VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
                ll_parent.addView(ll_children);
            }
            holder.cardView.addView(ll_parent);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.grandparent_cardview, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.bt_delete:

                break;

            case R.id.bt_edit:

                break;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        }
    }
}
```

**What's wrong with the code above? Is there a better way to add multiple rows (of same type) to a single CardView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added a background color to the linear layout (layout that repeats within each card as separate rows). Though this solved the problem, I'm still unaware what caused the views to overlap while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you certainly might want to check are your layout parameters. You have a 3-tier view hierarchy and things can get jumbled up if your layout parameters aren't properly set to "match_parent" and "wrap_content" in the appropriate places. I would suggest rewriting your layouts in XML and experimenting with your layout_width and layout_height parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Use getType method in adapter (you can set type in your cell model)
or use this library:https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-MultipleViewTypesAdapter